# I want to replace a parents scroll to popup's scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery.fracs for minimap which marking current location in page.
so when I scroll page this minimap is working and marking current location.

Parents page is showing the calendar. When click the date in calendar, open the layer popup and is showing seats and minimap. minimap's code is in jsp which layer popup's code.
and layer popup has `overflow-x scroll`.

The problem is that minimap must work in layer popup not on parent page.
But it works on parents page's scroll instead of layer popup's scroll...

so I want to replace parent's `window.scrollleft` in jquery.fracs.js to layer popup's scroll.
But I changed the jquery.fracs.js all of the way but nothing changed. It is just same....

If u want, I can show the code...

----------------------------update-------------------------------------------

I delete all of chache then its working....
but main problem is still remain....

```
ofViewport: function (element, inContentSpace) {
        if (!element || element === document || element === window) {               
            return new Rect($window.scrollLeft(), $window.scrollTop(), $window.width(), $window.height());
        }
```

I think that I have to change `$window.scrollLeft()` to layer popup's scroll
but I don't know how to write that.....

## seat .select { width:100%; overflow-x:scroll; background:#fff; }

this is layer popup's css code.... how to write.....???

Comment: Show us what you've tried, so we can help you!

Comment: first i insert alert in jquery.fracs.js and but its not working.... its just nothing to changed....

Comment: /* jQuery.fracs 0.15.0 - http://larsjung.de/jquery-fracs/ */
(function () {
'use strict';
alert("start");
// Some often used references.
var $ = jQuery;
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);
var extend = $.extend;
var isFn = $.isFunction;
var mathMax = Math.max;
var mathMin = Math.min;
var mathRound = Math.round;
alert("start");                                                         like this.... and i replace some words to my div id... but its not working too....